# Enabling WiFi Hotspot on headless RPi Zero W

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Trying to setup a wifi hotspot (that doesn't require internet) on the RPi Zero W via SSH. I'm connected to the Pi via Wifi using the wpa_supplicant.conf to connect to an existing network. I'm unable to connect via OTG USB for some reason.

No matter what online tutorial or guide I follow it fails to work. When I reboot it won't create a network nor reconnect to the existing network.

Is this purely because I'm connected via wifi whilst editing wifi configs?

Has anyone tried this setup? Know any workarounds?

Comment: Also check out the [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

Comment: So you need be client and AP at same time? Is it correct? Did you try 
https://blog.ithasu.org/2017/11/raspberry-pi-0w-as-both-wifi-client-and-access-point/ or https://blog.thewalr.us/2017/09/26/raspberry-pi-zero-w-simultaneous-ap-and-managed-mode-wifi/